git bundle top level repo and also submodules
I need to transfer the Raspberry pi pico sdk to a computer with not access to github or indeed https access.  I tried the following steps:
mkdir pico
cd pico
git clone -b master https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk.git
cd  pico-sdk
git submodule update --init
git bundle create pico-sdk.bundle master

Then at computer with no internet access:
git clone pico-sdk.bundle
that works fine but I don't get any of the submodule files.  I can do the same bundling up for each submodule but that is going to be quite time consuming.  Is there a way to git bundle the submdule files too?

Once you cloned everything, you can simply copy the entire directory with subdirectories over to the target (optionally using your favorite file archive format like zip or .tar.gz) and it'll work just fine, no need to use git-specific tools.

"git bundle the submdule files too?" I'm sure there is no. git bundle bundles one repository and submodules are separate repositories. Actually I'm afraid you will have a lot of problems with submodules on an offline host. You'd need to change submodules URLs in .gitmodules in the superproject to clone/fetch the submodules bundles and that will make you superproject dirty. Next time you going to update the superproject you will need to update submodules, stash .gitmodules, update the superproject and unstash.

Why do you want repositories at the offline host? Would git archive with submodules suite you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46551763/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+archive
